# Javascript remove \n or \t in html content except within pre tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex, newline, pre

In Javascript, how to remove line break (\n or \t) in html string except within `<pre>` tags.

I use this code to remove line break:

```
htmlString.replace(/[\n\t]+/g,"");
```

However, it also removes \n\t in `<pre>` tag. How to fix it?

Comment: probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1952996

Comment: Have you considered not having them in the first place? There are plenty of server-side options for minifying your HTML source, which can include (conditionally) removing empty text nodes and otherwise reducing bandwidth needed for your page.

Comment: Show how you use this. We have no idea how pre tags are populated or what source of string is

Comment: Surely you would want to replace these characters with a space instead of with nothing? If you replace them with nothing, then 'abc\ndef\nghi' will turn into 'abcdefghi' when it probably ought to be 'abc def ghi'. But why bother? Except in elements with `white-space:pre` (such as `<pre>` tags), the browser won't render them as newlines or tabs anyway, and it will collapse consecutive whitespace characters into one, so there's no point in you doing it.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: I don't want process this task on server. Server have many tasks to do

Comment: @charlietfl: I display code string use prism so string have `<pre>` tags

Comment: @MichaelGeary: yes, thanks for your comment. I will consider replacing with whitespace

Comment: But why bother doing this at all? The browser will collapse all consecutive whitespace characters into a single space when it displays the elements.

Comment: @MichaelGeary: because when string come to sever, purifier will convert newline to <br> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start first by matching the text that need to be cleaned, which can only be:

- Text from the begining of the string to the next opening `<pre>` tag.
- Text from a closing `</pre>` tag to the next opening `<pre>` tag.
- Text from a closing `</pre>` tag to the end of the string.
- Text from the begining of the string to the end of the string (no `pre` elements in the string).

which can be described in regex as:

```
(?:^|<\/pre>)[^]*?(?:<pre>|$)/g
```

where `[^]` matches anything including new lines, and `*?` is a non-greedy quantifier to match as few times as possible.

---

Next, we get the matched text that need to be cleaned, so we clean it using the regex `/[\n\t]+/g`.

---

**Example:**

```js
var htmlString = "<body>\n\t<p>\n\t\tLorem\tEpsum\n\t</p>\n\t<pre>\n\t\tHello, World!\n\t</pre>\n\n\t<pre>\n\t\tThis\n\t\tis\n\t\tawesome\n\t</pre>\n\n\n</body>";

var preview = document.getElementById("preview");
preview.textContent = htmlString;

document.getElementById("remove").onclick = function() {
    preview.textContent = htmlString.replace(/(?:^|<\/pre>)[^]*?(?:<pre>|$)/g, function(m) {
        return m.replace(/[\n\t]+/g, "");
    });
}
```

```css
pre {
    background: #fffbec;
}
```

```html
<button id="remove">Remove</button>
The pre bellow is just used to show the string, it is not THE PRE.
<pre id="preview"></pre>
```

---

[**Regex101 Example**](https://regex101.com/r/5smyc5/1).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) in order to select all [text nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Element/nodeType) and apply your regex only to these nodes:

```js
//
// closest Polyfill from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest
//
if (window.Element && !Element.prototype.closest) {
  Element.prototype.closest = function (s) {
      var matches = (this.document || this.ownerDocument).querySelectorAll(s), i, el = this;
      do {
          i = matches.length;
          while (--i >= 0 && matches.item(i) !== el) {
          };
      } while ((i < 0) && (el = el.parentElement));
      return el;
  };
}


document.getElementById("remove").addEventListener('click',  function(e) {
    //
    // traverse the DOM
    //
    var walker = document.createTreeWalker(
            document.body,
            NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
            null,
            false
    );

    var node;
    while (node = walker.nextNode()) {
        if (node.parentElement.closest('PRE') != null) {
            node.textContent = node.textContent.replace(/[\n\t]+/g, "");
        }
    }
});
```

```css
pre {
    background: #fffbec;
}
```

```html
<button id="remove">Remove</button><br>



<pre>
    this is a pre tag

    with    tab
</pre>

<pre class="language-cpp">
  <code>
    void main() {
      printf("Hello");
    }
  </code>
</pre>

<p>
    first word

    new       end</p>
```

Comment: It doesn't work if I have the following code: <pre class="language-cpp"><code>void main() { 
   printf("Hello");
}</code></pre>

Comment: I use regex `(?:^|<\/pre>)[^]*?(?:<pre.*>|$)/g` and it works.

Comment: I apply ibrahim mahrir's method: `mystring.replace(/(?:^|<\/pre>)[^]*?(?:<pre.*>|$)/g, function(m) {
            return m.replace(/[\n\t]+/g, "");
        });`. What is different?

Comment: Yes, I have `<code>` tag in string. You can try it in https://regex101.com/r/5smyc5/2